# Visual Studio Code has a white bar (titlebar)

Tags: visual-studio-code, titlebar

ive installed visual studio code, and theres this annoying white bar that i cant get rid of, can somebody help?
ive tried changing my Window: Title Bar Style already but it doesnt help.
[the ugly white bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hg1B9.png)

**EDIT: after fiddling around for a while i figured out that i needed to reboot my system after changing the said setting.**

Comment: Glad you figured it out, but you shouldn't edit the solution into the question. Instead, post an "answer" below, and press the checkmark next to it to mark your problem as solved.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 4):

For those who are coming across this question, to resolve the white bar into the normal Vs Code style title bar proceed to `File → Preference → Settings → Window → Title Bar Style`, change it from native to custom.